# Ionic ng-pdfviewr

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, pdf-viewer, pdfviewer

I'm getting the following error in one of my functions on ionic:

```
 Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{detailMl.file}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: http://192.168.1.105/sonschool/upload/mm_learning/44ec994b4e8892932d979ac93d045fa0.pdf
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$sce/insecurl?p0=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.…%2Fsonschool%2Fupload%2Fmm_learning%2F44ec994b4e8892932d979ac93d045fa0.pdf
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7BdetailMl.fi…school%252Fupload%252Fmm_learning%252F44ec994b4e8892932d979ac93d045fa0.pdf
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (ionic.bundle.js:8890)
    at parseStringifyInterceptor (ionic.bundle.js:19022)
    at regularInterceptedExpression (ionic.bundle.js:21679)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch (ionic.bundle.js:21583)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:23062)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23333)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:18486)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18676)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:18617)
```

help me please.. 
this code work :

`$scope.pdfURL = "school.pdf";`

and then i change this code with:

`var baseUrl = 'http://192.168.1.105/sonschool/api/';
$http.get(baseUrl+'ambilDetailML/?id='+$stateParams.mlId).success(function(dataML) {
        //console.log(dataML);
        $scope.pdfURL = dataML.url_pdf;
    });`

Any idea about what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use external resource you have to whitelist them (that's why the local 'school.pdf' file works and the one using IP doesn't). The tutorial on how to do this can be found [here](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/05/whitelist-external-resources-for-use-in-ionic-framework/).

But, shortly, you should install the [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) plugin and add
the following to your `www/index.html` file right below the other meta tags:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`